# How do I stop the "Green double-underlined links pop-up ads" adware in Chromium?

Tags: debian, chrome, malware

**Summary:**

In the Chromium web browser (Debian), can you tell me how get rid of whatever is causing the behaviour called "Green Double-Underlined Links pop-up ads"? I'd
like to **stop** the behaviour, not just block it with some kind of blocker.

How can I prevent my laptop from being affected by this problem in the
future?

The problem is awful, and is really getting on my wick. (Not your fault of
course).  :-)

In the meantime, is is safe for me to continue to use my computer, and to use
the Internet? Thanks.

**Full details:**

1. About a week ago (starting about 12Aug14) I started getting green double-
   underlined links appearing under numerous words and phrases in web page text.
   Also, at the same time, intrusive adverts started appearing everywhere, on web
   pages. These aren't the usual ads on web pages but are new and extremely
   intrusive. The green double-underlined links are also very intrusive and
   misleading.

   I could tell that something new was going on.
2. The site 
   http://malwaretips.com/blogs/green-double-underlined-ads-removal/
   says that on Windows, the above problem is caused by ADWARE, and tells you how
   to remove it from Windows, but NOT from Linux. However, the site IS informative
   about what the adware is, and how it gets onto Windows.
3. I don't know if the double-underline problem etc is caused in Linux in the
   same way as Windows, but I followed 2 of the principles in the above removal
   guide:

   a) Checked for any new Chromium plugins that I don't think should be there. I
   did this by opening a new tab and entering "chrome://plugins". I've got 9
   plugins BUT NONE OF THEM SEEM TO BE NEW.

   b) Looked at what packages I've recently installed, to see if they look as
   though they might have secretly installed this adware at the same time.

   The 4 lines from the output below are my recently installed packages. I used the
   following command to list them:

   ```
   cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ "   
   014-08-03 21:17:12 install mencoder:i386 <none> 2:1.0~rc4.dfsg1+svn34540-1+b2  
   2014-08-05 20:01:42 install libgpac2:i386 <none> 0.5.0~dfsg0-1  
   2014-08-05 20:01:43 install gpac-modules-base:i386 <none> 0.5.0~dfsg0-1  
   2014-08-05 20:01:44 install gpac:i386 <none> 0.5.0~dfsg0-1
   ```

   I DON'T ACTUALLY KNOW IF ANY OF THESE PACKAGES COULD HAVE ADDITIONALLY INSTALLED THE ADWARE, *IF* that's how the problem occurs in Linux.
4. I've got just one Chromium extension, which is Adblock Plus v1.7.4, which has
   been there for some time.
5. Excuse my noddy wording, but I'm wondering if the double-underline etc
   behaviour is being caused by a program on the Internet (remote from my laptop),
   and not actually a program that's on my hard drive.
6. I would be very grateful if you could tell me how to stop this awful problem.

Comment: From original question poser: IMPORTANT: I'm convinced that this particular problem is NOT caused by just certain
websites deliberately generating the green double-underlined links and ads.
I say this because this problem is occuring WHOLESALE on most webpages that I
visit. It STARTED happening to me SUDDENLY, since about 12Aug14.

Comment: Discard the issue being exclusive to your browser - try using Iceweasel, Firefox, and Chrome, and report your findings.  Is the same happening in these browsers?  If so, are you connecting to the internet using a proxy, or maybe a shared access point where you live?  I have heard that some special software installed in routers/ap can do that (force ads and sponsored links in web pages)

Comment: It could even be the ISP doing it.

Comment: `echo rm -rf ~/.config/chrom*/` - if the result is a single directory - remove the `echo` and run it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Unix & Linux.